# pm-hibernate freezes and/or fails to resume on Dell XPS 13, 14.04, 3.19 kernel

Tags: 14.04, dell, suspend, hibernate

I'm running 14.04 on a new XPS 13. In order to support the newer hardware, I'm running a mainline 3.19 kernel.

Hibernate resume has been iffy with the entire 3.19 kernel line, but recently (3.19.5) `pm-hibernate` no longer works at all. The screen will either a) switch off momentarily, then back on with all inputs frozen or b) switch off entirely, and fail to resume upon power on (despite displaying the correct resume-from-uuid message).

I have enough swap space (and it has worked in the past), I have checked that the uuid is being correctly referenced, and nothing seems particularly amiss in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` (last 200 lines here: http://pastebin.com/1dvyHhmQ)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Having the same problem: Sometimes when i try to resume from hibernate the power button is lighted up but the screen is black, also the mouse doesn't seem to have power (light). My pm-suspend.log:
http://pastebin.com/HqCkyugV

Comment: @enspandi I may have found the problem on my end, but would like to see whether it helps you as well before posting it as a solution. In my case, because I was running a newer kernel my initramfs wasn't correctly configured. If you want, try this and let me know how it goes: make sure you have grub configured to resume from the uuid of your swap `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="RESUME=UUID=<your uuid>"`, then do `uname -r` to get the kernel name, and finally `sudo update-initramfs -u -k <your kernel name>` and `sudo update-grub`. Reboot and see if you can now successfully use `pm-hibernate`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error :/ ... suddenly it works quite well... but I also updated to the latest bios lately (don't know if that had an impact)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the situation I described running a non-stock kernel, the following solution worked. Depending on what kernel series you're using, YMMV:

You'll need to do these to get grub/initramfs set up correctly:

```
sudo blkid | grep swap <-- get your swap uuid
sudo <your_text_editor_here> /etc/default/grub <-- edit your grub file    
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="RESUME=UUID=<your_swap_uuid>" <-- add this to grub file
uname -r <-- get running kernel name
sudo update-initramfs -u -k <your_kernel_name> <-- init with the right kernel
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot, and then check for hibernate compatibility by doing `pm-hibernate` at the command line. Hope this helps someone else!